# text formatting in QTextEdit in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm new to PyQt programming and I've developed a GUI using PyQt4 designer and the GUI looks like the one in the picture:
[image]

When I click the check_inertia button the QTextEdit widget gets populated with the text shown in the picture. As we can see that the text appears to be messy, I need to control the formatting of the QTextEdit.

The check_inertia button reads the contents of a .txt file and then prints the following information in the QTextEdit widget, the text file appears to be in this way of format:

```
*  ============================== INERTIA ==============================
* File: /home/hamanda/Desktop/transfer/cradle_vs30_dkaplus01_fwd_dl140606_fem140704_v00.bif
* Solver: Nastran
* Date: 02/09/14
* Time: 08:35:30
* Text: 
* 
* Area                               +1.517220e+06
* Volume                             +5.852672e+06
*   
* Structural mass                    +4.594348e-02
* MASS elements                      +0.000000e+00
* NSM on property entry              +0.000000e+00
* NSM by parts (VMAGen and MPBalanc) +0.000000e+00
* NSM by NSMCreate                   +0.000000e+00
* Total mass                         +4.594348e-02
* 
* Center of gravity
* in the global         +1.538605e+02  +3.010898e+00  -2.524868e+02
* coordinate system
* 
* Moments of inertia    +8.346990e+03  +6.187810e-01  +1.653922e+03
* about the global      +6.187810e-01  +5.476398e+03  +4.176218e+01
* coordinate system     +1.653922e+03  +4.176218e+01  +7.746156e+03
* 
* Steiner share         +2.929294e+03  +4.016500e+03  +1.088039e+03
* 
* Moments of inertia    +5.417696e+03  +2.190247e+01  -1.308790e+02
* about the center      +2.190247e+01  +1.459898e+03  +6.835397e+00
* of gravity            -1.308790e+02  +6.835397e+00  +6.658117e+03
*  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So how can I get the exact formatting as seen above into the QTextEdit of the GUI. what should I use? Stylesheets? Help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use font `monospace` or `consola` or other font is use in console or programming. Your can set in style sheet;

```
QTextEdit {
    font: 10pt "Consolas";
}
```

put in your `QTextEdit`;

```
yourQTextEdit.setStyleSheet ('''
    QTextEdit {
        font: 10pt "Consolas";
    }
''')
```

Note : `QPlainTextEdit` also can use this and I recommend use this for show raw text only and implement same `QTextEdit`.

Comment: Now i have a small question suppose now i want to grab the contents of the table and the qtextedit into a file (basically copying the contents of table and qtextedit into a file), Can you help me how to do that because the gettext() method only works for qlineedit, what is for qtextedit @Kitsenu Meyoko

Comment: Copy in qtextedit, your can use `QString QTextEdit.toPlainText (self)`. But in qtable, Your have to convert from row & column in csv  or excel format your self.